How to create HTML meta titles and descriptions for multi-page lists or directories
I've searched for hours and cannot find a specific answer to my question. If SEO page titles and meta descriptions are supposed to be unique for every page, but you have a list or directory with numbered pages, how do you handle the title and meta descriptions?
I've seen numerous sites, such as ROM sites and software sites, that have lists with numbered pages, and the title and meta description are identical for every page. Is there a trick or some type of code that allows those pages to have identical titles and meta descriptions?
The website has a section that lists all updates/versions and it spans several pages. It has numbered page links at the bottom (1 2 3...) that you can click on to go to a particular page within the list.

You have to use next and prev.  Example for page 2.  This way, GSE understands that the page is split into multiple pages.
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com//page2">
    <link rel="prev" href="https://example.com/page1">
    <link rel="next" href="https://example.com//page3">


Just to clarify, should the canonical always remain as the first page or the current page? Also, what do you do for page 1—just not include a "prev"?
